# Looking for a regular expression to match following

Tags: python, regex

```
string = '***All Done***, ***Execution Success 5664 for $**$ files***'

re pattern = ([\w+].*[\$\*\*]\$.*[\w+]|[\w+])

output i'm getting: 'All Done***, ***Execution Success for $**$ files'
```

expected output: `All Done Execution Success 5664 for $**$ files`

Should get only alpha numeric characters and `$\*\*$`. Rest all should be cleared. Any help would be appreciated. In case if `$\*\*$` is not found on string, then it should return: `All Done Execution Success 5664 for files`.

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\*{3}(.*?)\*{3}|[^\w\s]', r'\1', string)` (this is for Python 3.5+)

Comment: This did not work for me. String i've provided is just an example. It is not necessary to start with '***'. It can be like 'Error not ** found. Restore $**$ again **'. In this case i'm expecting regex to return 'Error not found Restore $**$ again'

Comment: Then use the `r'(\$\*\*\$)|[^\w\s]'` regex with the same code as above.

Comment: Tried this: 're.sub(r'(\$\*\*\$)|[^\w\s]', r'\1', string)'. Got an exception: 

    "raise error, "unmatched group"
sre_constants.error: unmatched group"

Comment: So, your Python is older than 3.5. Use `re.sub(r'(\$\*\*\$)|[^\w\s]', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else '', string)`

Comment: Code worked now but it skipped '$**$' and it is not clean.

Got output like this: *a ll done *e xecution success 5664 for files.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53318578/3832970), with exact code, just copy/paste.

Comment: It worked with this code. re.sub(r'(\$\*\*\$)|[^\w\s]', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else '', string)..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for your provided examples (Python 3.6):

```
import re

strings = [
    '***All Done***, ***Execution Success 5664 for $**$ files***',
    'Error not ** found. Restore $**$ again **'
]

pattern = "\w+|\$\*\*\$"
cpattern = re.compile(pattern)

for string in strings:
    print(" ".join(cpattern.findall(string)))
```

Output:

> ```
>  All Done Execution Success 5664 for $**$ files
>  Error not found Restore $**$ again
> ```